# getElementById() fails to get element when display:none

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

We have several cases of `$get('foo')` or `document.getElementById('foo')` failing when the element being looked for has `style="display:none;"`. This seems to work in some browsers but not others; specifically the case shown below works fine in IE9 with compatibility mode but fails when compatibility mode is turned off.

Can anyone explain why this might happen, and how we can work around it? An example follows.

Our ASPX page contains

```
<span id="JobAddressCheckBoxWrapper" style="display: none;">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="JobAddressCheckBox" CssClass="DefaultTextCell" runat="server" Text="__Job address"
    Style="margin-right: 2em;" onclick="ShowJobAddress();" />
</span>
<span id="PredefinedReplyCheckBoxWrapper">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="PredefinedReplyCheckBox" CssClass="DefaultTextCell" runat="server"
    Text="__Pre-defined reply" onclick="ShowReplies()" AutoPostBack="false" Style="margin-right: 2em;" />
</span>
```

that results in this generated HTML

```
<span style="display: none;" id="JobAddressCheckBoxWrapper">
  <span style="margin-right: 2em;" class="DefaultTextCell">
    <input id="JobAddressCheckBox" onclick="ShowJobAddress();" name="JobAddressCheckBox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="JobAddressCheckBox">Job address</label>
  </span>
</span>
<span id="PredefinedReplyCheckBoxWrapper">
  <span style="margin-right: 2em;" class="DefaultTextCell">
    <input id="PredefinedReplyCheckBox" onclick="ShowReplies();" name="PredefinedReplyCheckBox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="PredefinedReplyCheckBox">Predefined reply</label>
  </span>
</span>
```

The following Javascript statements should result in the wrapper variables containing objects but in some browsers, or compatibility modes in IE9, the value of jobAddressWrapper is null. The value of predefinedReplyWrapper is never null. The only difference between them is that JobAddressCheckboxWrapper has `style="display:none;"`.

```
var jobAddressWrapper = $get('JobAddressCheckboxWrapper');
var predefinedReplyWrapper = $get('PredefinedReplyCheckBoxWrapper');
```

or

```
var jobAddressWrapper = document.getElementById('JobAddressCheckboxWrapper');
var jobAddressWrapper = document.getElementById('PredefinedReplyCheckBoxWrapper');
```

The HTML pattern with elements wrapped by a span is not relevant; there are other cases where elements are not wrapped by spans but can still not be reference if they have `style="display:none;"`.

**Updates (in response to comments, etc.):**

1. $get provides a shortcut to the getElementById method of the
   Sys.UI.DomElement class. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397717.aspx)
2. These calls are made in functions called both from  onload and
   in response to user interaction. The problem happens in either case.

Comment: What is `$get`? When/how are those lines of js executed?

Comment: Steve, what you saying sounds really, really strange. getElementById finds anything exist in current DOM tree, no matter with what display property setted.

Comment: also, please, edit the question to make it as self-consistent as possible, in this very case it is just not the best solution to provide a link to another question just to explain terminology used in the current question.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` seems to work fine for me on your hidden HTML in all versions of IE I tried right here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dtEGR/.  There must be something else wrong that you are being confused by because I don't think it's a problem with `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1):

This really is an odd problem to have, so before anything else check the code for typos and scope confusion!
Also this is really, *really* old - so hopefully you are not still having this problem. =)

One solution you might find, however, will often help when you are trying to work past such problems, or even better find their cause. Use jQuery selection `$('#AnyID')`, mind the css # syntax if you're not familiar.

Browsers have come a long way in attempting to be more compatible, with a long way to go. Earlier on I used jQuery quite often to deduce why a vanilla JS instruction was not working the way I intended it to in one browser and would work in another. Usually I would find that I didn't understand JS well enough and jQuery just knew already what I needed learn =)

Comment: Thanks, no not having the problem any more. I forget how exactly but we found some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is perhaps not relevant to every instance of the problem, but I encountered it while using ASP.NET Master pages;

with ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent", my div id="IdValidationErrorDiv" actually has a rendered id of "MainContent_IdValidationErrorDiv".

calling getElementById with this id succeeded.