# Get element by id when it is hidden and display:none

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using `React` and I am trying to get an element by `id`. I know that I should use `ref` for that, but I can not make it working. However, `d3` works: it gets the elements I want, but not the elements that have `visibility: hidden` and `display:none` on them. Is it possible to make `d3` select the hidden elements? Here is part of the code that I have:

```
<div style={{display: this.state.fullAnalysisDone && this.state.activeKey === 0 ? 'block' : 'none', 
      visibility: this.state.fullAnalysisDone && this.state.activeKey === 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>
        {
        this.get_analysis_charts(this.chartTypes[this.state.activeKey]).map((chart_img, idx) => {
          return <img id = {'chart_' + this.state.activeKey + '_' + idx} src = {chart_img} style = {{width:"400px"}}
            onClick={() => this.clickedResultPageImg(idx)}/>
        })
      }
    </div>
```

When I try getting `img` by `id`: `d3.select(chartId).node()` that are inside the hidden div, I get nothing. Here is probably the same issue that is unanswered on `stackoverflow`:

[getElementById() fails to get element when display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087532/getelementbyid-fails-to-get-element-when-displaynone)

Comment: If the element is in the DOM, you should find it, make sure the element is in the DOM and you're using the correct selector.

Comment: When I added all of the images in a div without any styling, it is working, but with `display:none` it is not

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko What's the value of `chartId` in your select statement? Does it have the leading `#` which is necessary to select by id?

Comment: Yes, it does. It has the form `#chart_0_0` , `#chart_0_1`, etc.

Comment: As rioV8 has shown this does generally work as expected. Can you set up an executable demo to replicate this issue?

Comment: Will see. Most probably I can just add here all of the code that I have. The code is inside a modal in React-Bootstrap. There are `Navs` with pagination and images everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

In my browser it works for `getElementById` and for `d3.select()` even when both the `div` and the `p` are `{ display:none; visibility: hidden; }`.

With hidden `p` and also with hidden `img`.

```js
function changePara(paraId, newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(paraId);
  console.log("changePara", paraId, elem);
  if (elem) { elem.style.color = newColor; }
}

function changeColor(newColor) {
  changePara('para1', newColor);
  changePara('para2', newColor);
}

function changeParaD3(paraId, newColor) {
  var elem = d3.select(`#${paraId}`);
  console.log("changeParaD3", paraId, elem.size());
  if (elem.size()) { elem.style("color", newColor); }
}

function changeColorD3(newColor) {
  changeParaD3('para1', newColor);
  changeParaD3('para2', newColor);
}
```

```css
.nosee { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
#para2 { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<div class="see"><p id="para1">Some text</p></div>
<div class="nosee"><img id="para2" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg"/></div>


<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="changeColorD3('blue');">blue-d3</button>
<button onclick="changeColorD3('red');">red-d3</button>
```